# store/load numpy array from binary files

Tags: python, file, binaryfiles

I would like to store and load numpy arrays from binary files. For that purposes, I created two small functions. Each binary file should contain the dimensionality of the given matrix.

```
def saveArrayToFile(data, fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'w') as file:
        a = array.array('f')
        nSamples, ndim = data.shape
        a.extend([nSamples, ndim]) # write number of elements and dimensions
        a.fromstring(data.tostring())
        a.tofile(file)


def readArrayFromFile(fileName):
    _featDesc = np.fromfile(fileName, 'f')
    _ndesc = int(_featDesc[0])
    _ndim  = int(_featDesc[1])
    _featDesc = _featDesc[2:]
    _featDesc = _featDesc.reshape([_ndesc, _ndim])

    return _featDesc, _ndesc, _ndim
```

An example on how to use the functions is:

```
myarr=np.array([[7, 4],[3, 9],[1, 3]])
saveArrayToFile(myarr,'myfile.txt')
_featDesc, _ndesc, _ndim = readArrayFromFile('myfile.txt')
```

However, an error message of 'ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged' is shown. My arrays can be of size MxN and MxM. Any suggestions are more than welcomed.
I think the problem might be in the saveArrayToFile function.

Best wishes,

Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) (and [numpy.load](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load)) to dump (retrieve) numpy arrays to (from) a binary file.

Comment: OK, thanks! however, I really need to store the MxN dimension of the array into the file.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to name the file something like `myfile_MxN.npy`?

Comment: @Javier: I could understand why you might want to save the dimension of the array in say the first few bytes of the file if you wanted to grab that data without reading the entire file. However, `_featDesc, _ndesc, _ndim = readArrayFromFile('myfile.txt')` suggests you are reading the entire file (no peeking at header bits). So why not simply use `arr=np.load(...)`, and then `_ndesc,_ndim = arr.shape`?