# Python - Store individual numpy matrices to minimize memory on disk and loading time. Binary files?

Tags: python, binary, storage, loading

I wrote some code to generate a large dataset of complex numpy matrices for ML applications, which I would like to somehow store on disk.

The most suitable idea seems to be saving the matrices into separate binary files. However, commands such as `bytearray()` seems to flatten the matrices into 1D arrays, thus losing the information over the matrix shape.

I guess I might need to fill each line independently, maybe using an additional for loop, but this would also require a for loop when loading and re-assembling the matrix.

What would be the correct procedure for storing those matrices in a way that minimizes the amount of space on disk and loading time?

Comment: Apache Parquet is very efficient both in terms of storage space and loading time: https://parquet.apache.org/

Comment: What type of matrices? If numpy then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052669/store-load-numpy-array-from-binary-files

Comment: Yes. it's numpy matrices, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I had a look at your solution, but it is not clear to me why the guy stores `a.fromstring(data.tostring())`, which creates a binary array using `tostring()`, then it converts back to a float array with `.fromstring()`. I might be wrong but, to me, he looks like he is not storing a binary array.